# c# Open IE From Scheduled Task

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, task

I have a c# console application that I want to run from task scheduler that has 2 main functions: 1) Closes all Internet Explorer processes; and 2) Restarts Internet Explorer and loads the appropriate website.

The console app does exactly what it is supposed to do if run from the command line, but fails if executed from Task Scheduler.

The app is designed to run on the client computer the only function of which is to load a single website and broadcast the website to our internal TV Channel 195.  We have connection issues with our ISP and while the connection issue is usually temporary, Internet explorer needs to be restarted to re-show the website.

I want to set it up to run multiple times each day to eliminate any possible connection issues between the web server and the client.

```
private static void StartExplorer()
{
    Process _process;
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "iexplore.exe",
        Arguments = "-noframemerging -private -k \"http://tv.TheelmAtClark.Com\""
    };
    try{
        _process = Process.Start(psi);
    }
    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to run the app using task scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you look at alternative approaches, if possible.

A Firefox plugin like [Reload Every](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) is designed to do just this. I use this in our to project to a big screen TV.

However, if you are keen on doing this via Internet explorer, again there are two approaches

1) Something similar to the Firefox plugin I mentioned above - [Autorefresher for IE](http://download.cnet.com/AutoRefresher-for-IE/3000-12512_4-10062693.html)

2) If you insist on having a task scheduler, as you mentioned above, here is how I think you can do it-

To kill all Internet Explorer instances, use [PSKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx). Invoke it via `Process.Start` with arguments to kill Internet Explorer.

To launch a new instance, try invoking `Process.Start` with `UseShellExecute=true`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not married to IE, and will give the Firefox reloader a try. Thanks for the very prompt response.

Comment: Great - if you are provisioning VMs and want to avoid the hassle of adding another install to Firefox, Opera comes with "Reload Every" feature out of the box.